# Failed to instantiate component or class Error in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am facing below error while configuring Yii2 application.

> Class "common\components\Request" does not exist in D:\Wamp\www\stage\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php

Request.php exists in correct path.

[image]

I have tried to run composer update to fix it, but it doesn't work